# Find an Orientation for a complete Bipartite graph $K_{r,s}$, where $r,s \geq 2$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Find an Orientation for a complete Bipartite graph $K_{r,s}$, where $r,s \geq 2$

I'm assuming i need to find a graph which is connected and that each edge belongs to a circuit, hence this would be a orientation of the graph?

Considering we have a complete bipartite graph I think the answer would be a circle circuit? however, how would i show this

Comment: The question does not ask for any requirement for the orientation, and it does not need to be a circuit. You can just assign the direction to let one component be the starting vertices and the other component be the ending vertices.

Comment: there is a theorem that states "given a connected graph, $G$. $G$ is orientable if and only if each edge of $G$ belongs to at least one circuit" ... so surely the edges need to be in a circuit?

Comment: also, i can't just assign directions as the question is asking me to find an orientation for $K_{r,s}$ not simply one graph but essentially all of them

Comment: It seems you are asking for "a strong orientation" instead of "an orientation" then, you might want to add that to the question.

Comment: nope the question is simply orientation, i must be understanding this incorrectly, so what needs to be done?

Comment: An orientation is basically any assignment of direction to edges without any restriction. So If it is just a simple orientation then you can just assign all edge to go from $r$ side to $s$ side. However if you are talking about strong orientation, which requires any pair of vertices reachable from each other then a circuit in the original graph is required.

Comment: okay this makes sense, but how would i phrase the answer to the above question? could you possibly write out an answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the simple orientation, If you let the vertices be $\{u_1,u_2,...,u_r\}$ and $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_s\}$.

Then a simple orientation would just be "Let the direction of $u_iv_j$ start from $u_i$ and end with $v_j$ for all $1\leq i \leq r,1\leq j\leq s$".

For a strong orientation case, a valid solution would be "Let the direction of $u_iv_j$ start from $u_i$ and end with $v_j$ for all $1 \leq i \leq r, 1 \leq j \leq s$ where $i+j$ is even and start from $v_j$ and end with $u_i$ where $i+j$ is odd.".

To show this is a valid solution,

(1) Consider two arbitrary vertices from different components, $u_i,v_j$, if $i+j$ is even then $u_iv_j$ would be a path from $u_i$ to $v_j$, if $i+j$ is odd then $u_iv_{j+1}u_{i+1}v_j$ (If $i=r$ change $i+1$ to $i-1$ and if $j=s$ change $j+1$ to $j-1$) would be a path from $u_i$ to $v_j.$ Similarly, if $i+j$ is even then $v_ju_i$ is a path from $v_j$ to $u_i$ and if $i+j$ is odd then $v_ju_{i+1}v_{j+1}u_i$ (change the $+1$ to $-1$ for $i=r$ or $j=s$) would be a path from $v_j$ to $u_i$.

(2) Consider two arbitrary vertices from the same component, say $u_i,u_k$. Then from the previous case we know there exist a path $p_1$ from $u_i$ to $v_1$ and a path $p_2$ from $v_1$ to $u_k$ so $p_1p_2$ would be a path from $u_i$ to $u_k$.

Comment: would it be possible for you to extend this answer for a strong orientation aswell? just to help me fully understand both concepts

Comment: I updated the answer with a proof for the strong orientation case.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an orientation, the problem is trivial and the assumption that $r,s\ge2$ is not needed. I guess you want a *strongly connected* orientation, i.e., one with a directed path from any vertex to any other vertex. Let $(R,S)$ be a bipartition, $|R|=r\ge2,\ |S|=s\ge2.$ Partition $R$ into two disjoint nonempty sets $R_1,R_2$ and partition $S$ into two disjoint nonempty sets $S_1,S_2.$ Then
$$\{xy:x\in R_1,y\in S_1\}\cup\{xy:x\in S_1,y\in R_2\}\cup\{xy:x\in R_2,y\in S_2\}\cup\{xy:x\in S_2,y\in R_1\}$$
is a strongly connected orientation. (Here $xy$ denotes a directed edge from $x$ to $y.$)